# Recursive queries with two aggregate columns

Tags: postgresql

I want to compute certain statistics montly in a postgres database

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE totals(start, t_end, null_count, not_null_count) AS (
    VALUES (date_trunc('month', current_date + interval '1 month'),
            date_trunc('month', current_date + interval '2 months'),
            0::bigint)
  UNION
    SELECT start - interval '1 month' as start, start as t_end,
      (SELECT count(*) filter (WHERE flag IS NULL) FROM tbl
        WHERE created_at >= start
          and created_at < t_end
          and deleted_at < current_timestamp
      ) as null_count,
      (SELECT count(*) filter (WHERE flag IS NOT NULL) FROM tbl
        WHERE created_at >= start
          and created_at < t_end
          and deleted_at < current_timestamp
      ) as not_null_count
    FROM totals
    WHERE start > current_date - interval '1 year'
)
select * from totals
```

This would give me what I want, but would scan `tbl` twice.
Is there a way to to this scanning only once, like one would do in a plain query

```sql
SELECT count(*) filter (WHERE flag IS NULL) null_count,
       count(*) filter (WHERE flag IS NOT NULL) not_null_count, FROM tbl
        WHERE created_at >= start
          AND created_at < t_end
          AND deleted_at < current_timestamp
```

I know I could group by `date_trunk('month', created_at)` but doing that causes the query to sort the rows, and this is very costly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can update your query to -

```
WITH RECURSIVE totals(start, t_end, null_count, not_null_count) AS (
    VALUES (date_trunc('month', current_date + interval '1 month'),
            date_trunc('month', current_date + interval '2 months'),
            0::bigint)
  UNION
    SELECT start - interval '1 month' as start, start as t_end,
           count(*) filter (WHERE flag IS NULL) as null_count,
           count(*) filter (WHERE flag IS NOT NULL) as not_null_count
    FROM tbl
    JOIN totals ON created_at >= start
               and created_at < t_end
   WHERE start > current_date - interval '1 year'
     AND deleted_at < current_timestamp
)
select * from totals
```

Comment: This query does not work, the first thing would be a complaint that `start` and `t_end` should be in a group by. But if I do that it will tell that aggregate functions are not allowed in a recursive query's recursive term.

Comment: Is it possible to convert aggregate function to analytical function using OVER clause?

Comment: What do you mean?